# Removing white-space in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php script which returns `0.28`. This is then fetched to HTML using AJAX, and inserted into a span. The problem is, it is inserted with 5 spaces and what appears to be a newline. jQuery then sees that as a change and updates the existing span with the new value when there is no change. It appears that the whitespace does not come from the php. I have tried:

- to trim() and ltrim() the php to get rid of whitespace
- remove php exit tag
- white-space-collapsing: discard; in the css and using the !important tag
  (this is not being read and the chrome yellow alert is on it)
- trimming the response with jquery
- using html notes to cut the space

Dumping the php variable:

```
string(4) "0.28"
```

This is how my browser returns it

```
   <span id="response1" style="display: inline;">*5spaceshere*    
   0.28</span>
```

This is my script

```
$(function () {
    function update() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "balancefetch.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                var trimmedResponse = $.trim(response)
                if (trimmedResponse != $("#response1").html()) {
                    $("#response1").fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $("#response1").html(response);
                        $("#response1").fadeIn();
                    });
                } else {}
            }

        });
    }
    setInterval(update, 5000);
    update();
});
```

And my html

```
<div id="balance-div"><!--
--><p class="balance">Balance<span id="response1">Loading...</span></p><!--
--></div>
```

php

```
$balance = ltrim($balance);
echo $balance;
```

`$balance` holds 0.26

Comment: Please show your PHP.

Comment: I'm not allowed to show all of it, but what i can i will

Comment: Whitespace is generally ignored in html, why is this an issue?

Comment: Because i'm checking with AJAX to see if the content is different to what php returns, and with whitespace it will flag up as different everytime.

Comment: You have already used `$.trim()`, the issue seems to be something else.

Comment: you could probably do this `.replace(/\s+/, "") `

Comment: I think it would be better to find 'why' it inserts 5 whitespaces there. I know you can't show your code, but maybe you should try to debug like `var_dump( $balance );` and look if there are whitespaces, if yes, go steps before and look what actually adds the whitespaces there. Btw. why you can't show your code? I mean you could hide important links or change their names.. it's not like we all never sawn PHP code or know how to manage it by ourselfs, even if not, your code won't help at all to "steal" something.

Comment: Hey, var dump returns       string(4) "0.28"

Comment: So could it be possible that they are whitespaces inside your script? Maybe before your `<?php` Opening Tag or somewhere between the lines? I remember when `<?php  {whitespaces}   session_start();` would occur a `header already sent` error, because there are white spaces before or something like `?>   {whitespaces} ` inside a script that you use and this also counts as white space, so some people would tend to say that you shouldn't use the PHP-Close Tag if there is nothing else there anymore, because PHP won't fail doing that and this could prevent such failures

Comment: Good suggestion, I checked for this, found nothing.I fetch using SQL if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $balance = $row["credits"];
  $balance = ltrim($balance);
  //echo $balance;
  var_dump( $balance );

Comment: I am not using an end tag for this reason.

Comment: Do you include another scripts before? Like a config file for DB connection, maybe there is something that makes the whitespaces. Try creating another file which includes all of them and output some random content and look if there still are whitespaces, then remove one include by one and look if at any time the whitespaces are gone

Comment: Fixed, was in the config file, you can post it as an official answer, checking included filed. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after testing and going trough several methods finding where the problem is, the source for this problem was found.

The main part why not using technics like `trim` or a RegEx to remove whitespaces is, because that would fix the current problem, but not the source, so this would be just a bad workaround, so it was important to find the source.

The source problem was inside the configuration file, which had some whitespaces inside it and after including it inside the script, which is loaded via AJAX, the whitespaces also were included.

**Solution**: Remove the whitespaces of the config file and/or just remove the `?>` PHP-Ending Tag.

For further debuging steps, look into the comment section of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ob_clean()` which clears buffer that had unwanted newline