# JS comparison not working when getting XML response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, response

[image]

I am getting data as **"success"** but when I am comparing it to print some result it is not going in if part rather it is executing else part.

As you can see in the image on the right-hand side I **console log data** which gives `success`(on left side console page).

Again when i am comparing data with the exact same string **"success"** it is not printing "hello" rather it goes to the else part and prints "hellddo".

Comment: It looks like console.log(data) is outputting " success" (with a space in front of it).

Comment: Use `if(data.trim() == "success"){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Provide The Code Of Both Your PHP File & Your JS Code Instead Of The Image. So That Code Can Be Easily Copy Pasted And Executed Fast Instead Of Typing It Out.

Coming To A Solution, As @Swati Commented, Try Trimming The data Variable To Remove Any Whitespaces:
`console.log(data.trim() == 'success')`

And, To Fix The Problem On The PHP Side, You Should Just Check If You Accidently Typed 
`" success"` Instead Of `"success"`

Comment: your answer is working ..there was white space in start.
this post helped in solving the problem. Thanks again <3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911920/removing-white-space-in-ajax-response/30912864